# Vertically center divs to the left and right of an enlarged div in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `ul` of `div`s in a grid that are all the same size and distance from each other. When the user selects one of the divs, it enlarges. This makes the divs to the left and right of this div look bad. I'd like them to be vertically centered so it doesn't look as off. Here's a picture of what I have:

[image: What I have]

Here's what I want:

[image: What I want]

My current CSS (I'm using SASS) is:

```
#grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow-y: auto;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        background: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .selected {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

When the user selects one of the divs, I give it the class `.selected`, so it becomes larger than the others.

Also, how do I animate the centering/enlarging?

Comment: `vertical align: middle` should fix it (middle not center, my bad). let me know if it works and i'll post as an answer

Comment: @duxfox Thank you! that did it...you can post as answer if you want me to accept it. Bonus points if you can explain how to animate when adding a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `vertical-align: middle` to make the vertical alignment centered. To animate you can add a transition on `all` or just on `width` and `height`, something like this:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  or transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}

.selected {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```